# Range Slider is not Working in VF

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have one problem in which I am not able to see my Range Slider. In console it gives me this error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
     <apex:page controller="AttachmentListWithFilterController" sidebar="false">
          <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js')}"/>
                 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')}"/>
                 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css')}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            //This will load as soon as the page is ready and will setup our slider
            var str;
            $(document).ready(function(){
              var i=0;
              str = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value;
              var b=document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pblock.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMax}').value// On this line it is showing error


              console.log('Value of b'+b);

                $("#slider-range").slider({ //This line creates a slider on the DIV specified, options are passed arguments, comma separated below
                    range: true, //This give the slider and top and bottom
                    min: 0, //Min value for slider
                    max: 40, //Max value for slider

                    values: ['{!sSliderFieldMin }','{!sSliderFieldMax }'], //Start values for the slider
                    slide: function(event, ui){ //This function executes every time slider is moved and applies the slider values to the inputHidden fields as well as the output below the slider
                        document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pblock.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMin}').value = ui.values[0];

                        document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pblock.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMax}').value = ui.values[1];
                       $("#amountValue").html( + ui.values[0] + 'KB - ' + ui.values[1] + 'KB');

                        //callfind();
                        //console.log(i++);
                    },
                    stop:function(event,ui){console.log(ui);callfind();}   
                });  

              $("#amountValue").html( + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + 'KB - ' + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + 'KB');
            });
        </script>
     <apex:Form id="form">
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Filter" collapsible="true" columns="2" id="pblock">
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

                            <div id="slider-range" style="font-size: 90%; margin-top: 0.5em;"></div>
                            <div id="amountValue" style="text-align: center;"></div>
                            <apex:commandButton value="searchByRange" action="{!searchByRange}" reRender="PGTable"/>   

                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                   </apex:pageBlockSection>

                      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="slidervalue">

                 <apex:inputHidden value="{!sSliderFieldMin}" id="idInputHiddenMin"/>
                 <apex:inputHidden value="{!sSliderFieldMax}" id="idInputHiddenMax"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>    
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I am getting both `sSliderFieldMax` and `sSliderFieldMin` from controller.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?